# my dictionary is part of a dictionary, why?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

My "server" receives a POST request every time a person open the WebSite, bringing a JSON-encoded JavaScript dictionary (object). When the request comes to me (server) I turn it into dictionary using Flask's `request.form.to_dict ()`, but it returns my dictionary inside another, like: `{'{" User ":" test " , "Password": "123"} ':' '}`, leaving it inaccessible for saving to the database. **Why is my dictionary inside another?**

---

In javascript: I tried to turn into json and put in a variable. already tried to create, transform and send the dictionary in the same line.

In python: I've tried using another json tool, other request values and using flask jsonify.

**Javascript:**

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('POST','', true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
 //I "tried application/json" too
var dict={
    User:'test',  //I tried " 'User':'test' " too
    Password:'123'
};

ajax.send(JSON.stringify(dict));
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        var data = ajax.responseText;
        console.log(data+'abacate');
    }
}
```

**Python/Flask:**

```
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        system('msg UCQ POST')
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        print('post:', data)


    elif request.method == 'GET':
        system('msg UCQ GET')

    else:
        system('msg UCQ ' + request.method)

    return render_template('index.html')
```

I expected to receive this: `{'User': 'test', 'Password': '123'}`

But i receive this:`{'{"User":"test","Password":"123"}': ''}`. look at the two quotes left at the end of it, showing that he is part of another dictionary.

---

If anyone needs the complete .py file, let me know.
I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest.send` can be invoked with a `Document` or a `BodyInit`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Otherwise, the browser is treating the JSON string of the request data as a field.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('POST', '', true);
var fd = new FormData();

fd.append('User', 'test');
fd.append('Password', '123');
ajax.send(fd);
```